# How would you use querySelector to get this element?

Tags: javascript, html

How would you use the `querySelector()` method to get the outlined `input` if it didn't have a `class` attribute:

```js
document.querySelector('.red').style.outline = '1px solid red';
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input>
  </p>
  <span></span>
  <input class="red">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the only `input` directly inside the `<div>`, so you can just use `div > input`:

```js
document.querySelector('div > input').style.outline = '1px solid red';
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input>
  </p>
  <span></span>
  <input>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: _"the only `input` there"_? You mean besides the other two? Your code is fine but the prose is a little confusing

Comment: Getting to 100k cures blindness. Hope you **see** it today 

Answer (score 1):

If the point is to get the last one, use `querySelectorAll` instead and get/affect the last item. This is less brittle in the case of a markup change.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('div input'); // whatever is specific enough

inputs[ inputs.length -1 ].style.outline = '1px solid red';
```

```css
/* not this selector! see P.S. */
input:last-of-type { background: lightgrey; border: 1px solid grey; }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input>
  </p>
  <span></span>
  <input>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

P.S. You might think you could use `input:last-of-type`, but no! `last-of-type` is very broad, and in this case matches every input, as you can see from the CSS included above.

Answer (score 0):

you can use element>element selector is used to select elements with a specific parent. base on this link:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp

for example:

```
document.querySelector('div > input').style.outline = '1px solid red';
```

that select all input elements where the parent is a  element

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the style to all the inputs in your HTML then use following

```
window.onload = function(){
  var inputElems = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  var index
  for ( index = 0; index < inputElems.length; index++) {
    inputElems[index].style.outline = '1px solid red';

  }
 }
```

you can also apply style by calling a method on button click

```
function myFunction() {
    var inputElems = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    var index
    for ( index = 0; index < inputElems.length; index++) {
    inputElems[index].style.outline = '1px solid red';
    }
 }

<button onclick="myFunction()">Apply Outline</button>
```